# How to use condition in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use sql to save the process of moving goods between 2 shops.
I have two tables:
A:

| id | shop | good_sn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | aaa |
| 2 | 1 | bbb |
| 3 | 1 | ccc |
| 4 | 2 | ddd |

B:

| id | shop_from | shop_to | good_sn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | bbb |

and I want to select a table like this:

| shop | good_sn |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa |
| 1 | ccc |
| 2 | ddd |
| 2 | bbb |

Does anyone have any query ideas for this case?

Comment: Do you want to remove the record from Table B and update the record in Table A?

Comment: can you create example on http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?
It can be done using union query and couple of joins.

Comment: I want to use select to get the results when the transfer between 2 shops is completed

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Normally you would do this by updating table 1 to show the new state of stock in both locations.  Or by holding stock in some sort of ledger. stock movement transactions table. (Location, Item, Quantity CHANGE, etc..)

Comment: What if B contains `(1, 1, 2, bbb), (2, 2, 3, bbb)` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use this

```
SELECT COALESCE(b.shop_to, a.shop) AS shop, 
    a.good_sn
FROM table_a a 
LEFT JOIN table_b b 
ON a.shop = b.shop_from AND a.good_sn = b.good_sn
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: And if the goods subsequently move back from shop 2 to Shop 1 or move from Shop 2 to Shop 3 this stops working immediately, right?  The whole architecture needs rethinking.

Comment: @JeffUK if goods move more than 1 time, my query fails to work. In that case I think ` `table_b` should have a time stamp or order to track moving order, that will make us easier to select/update... to get the last location of goods.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach Thank you very much! Maybe my question is a bit confusing because my English is not good but this is the result I want.

Comment: @nhhthong as a Warehouse Management implementer/developer, I'm 99% sure this is not the result you want.  Certainly not as the basis of a long-term sustainable solution,  if it's a school project you'll probably be fine! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059682/database-design-inventory-and-sales-system is a good primer

Comment: @PhamX.Bach if you did that, then deleted table A, you're much closer to a robust solution actually.  Table A becomes entirely redundant it's just a view on Table B.